# Sci-fi book about a guy who hears tell of a planet with no crime, taxes, or divorces, and decides to check it out for himself

Tags: story-identification, novel

I cannot remember name of the book. A stranger tells the guy in the pub about planet he visited that is a paradise with no crime, taxes, divorces, etc.

The guy travels to the planet and gets robbed in the street by a tax collector, because there’s no taxes. He falls in love and marries a woman and finds out that all married women are put in some kind of cryogenic chamber and only let out on weekends. He vows never to do it. His wife starts an affair out of boredom and her lover needs to kill him because there’re no divorces.

He escapes back to Earth. He also became a president at one point.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I think the story is at least 30 years old

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[A Ticket to Tranai](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18521753-a-ticket-to-tranai)* by Robert Sheckley. Not a novel, but a (70 page) novella.

> “I heard that there has been no war of any sort on Tranai for four hundred years.”
> “Six hundred,” Melith corrected. “And none in sight.”.
> “Someone told me that there is no crime on Tranai.”.
> “None whatsoever.”.
> “And therefore no police force or courts, no judges, sheriffs, marshals, executioners, truant officers or government investigators. No prisons, reformatories or other places of detention.”.
> “We have no need of them,” Melith explained, “since we have no crime.”.
> “I have heard,” said Goodman, “that there is no poverty on Tranai.”.
> “None that I ever heard of,” Melith said cheerfully. “Are you sure you won’t have a cigar?”

Comment: This is it. Robert Sheckley. Now I can re-read it.

Comment: Please click on the checkmark to show that it is the correct answer.

Comment: The ISFDB calls it a novella, and it took up 38 printed pages in [*Galaxy*, Oct. 1955](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v11n01_1955-10/page/n7/mode/2up) including some illos. I'd like to read that 70-page version, if it's for real. Is there any evidence for its existence besides that Goodreads page?

Comment: @user14111 - I suspect that the 70 pages is what you get if you split 40 magazine pages into book-sized pages

Comment: I wrote "novella" but that was a typo; the ISFDB calls "A Ticket to Tranai" a novelette. It's 40 pages (108-147) in my 1962 Ballantine paperback edition of Sheckley's collection *Citizen in Space*. Maybe it's 70 pages in some foreign translation.